# Docker image builds on laptop, not on Digital Ocean - my understanding of Docker is shattered

Tags: python, docker, digital-ocean, dockerfile

I have a non-trivial `Docker` environment for a Python app I'm building (see below for full `Dockerfile`). On my MacBook (with `Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd`) I am able to build the `Docker` image, run the container and the app works fine.

I now want to test the app on Digital Ocean. I have only ever used Docker on my laptop up to this point. I created a droplet using the `Ubuntu Docker 1.10.3 on 14.04` image. I SSH'd in, cloned my git repo, executed the `docker build` command, but I got an error during the build (see bottom for full stack trace).

```
Exception: Cython-generated file 'pandas/index.c' not found.
           Cython is required to compile pandas from a development branch.
           Please install Cython or download a release package of pandas.
```

This is a valid exception, but my questions is: ***Why would the same `Dockerfile` and `docker build` command successfully build on one machine, but raise an exception on another?*** My understanding of Docker was that it prevented this sort of thing from happening by building the environment from scratch using just the Dockerfile...I just can't wrap my head around what is causing this exception on one machine and not the other.

---

**`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV HOME /root

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y gfortran 
RUN apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip 
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev
RUN apt-get install -y subversion
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get clean

# Install Python packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install bottleneck
RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install scipy
RUN pip install Flask
RUN pip install uwsgi

# Build OpenCV and dependencies
RUN cd && wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip \
    && git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git \
        && unzip 3.1.0.zip \
        && cd opencv-3.1.0 && mkdir build && cd build \
        && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
             -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
             -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
             -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
             -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
             -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. \
    && make -j2 && make install \
        && cd && rm -rf opencv-3.1.0 && rm 3.1.0.zip

# Build HDF5
RUN cd ; wget https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/hdf5-1.8.16.tar.gz
RUN cd ; tar zxf hdf5-1.8.16.tar.gz
RUN cd ; mv hdf5-1.8.16 hdf5-setup
RUN cd ; cd hdf5-setup ; ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/
RUN cd ; cd hdf5-setup ; make && make install

# Cleanup
RUN cd ; rm -rf hdf5-setup
RUN apt-get -yq autoremove
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install Python packages with dependencies on HDF5
RUN pip install tables
RUN pip install h5py
RUN pip install -U scikit-image

RUN rm -fr /root/.cache

# Update environment and working directories
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN mv config ../config

# Setup config
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

RUN ln -s /config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
RUN ln -s /config/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**`Stack Trace`**

```
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tseries/tests/data
    copying pandas/tseries/tests/data/series_daterange0.pickle -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tseries/tests/data
    copying pandas/tseries/tests/data/frame.pickle -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tseries/tests/data
    copying pandas/tseries/tests/data/dateoffset_0_15_2.pickle -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tseries/tests/data
    copying pandas/tseries/tests/data/daterange_073.pickle -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tseries/tests/data
    copying pandas/tseries/tests/data/series.pickle -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tseries/tests/data
    copying pandas/tseries/tests/data/cday-0.14.1.pickle -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/tseries/tests/data
    UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/_version.py
    set build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/_version.py to '0.18.0'
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-OD55P2/pandas/setup.py", line 604, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-OD55P2/pandas/setup.py", line 316, in build_extensions
        self.check_cython_extensions(self.extensions)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-OD55P2/pandas/setup.py", line 313, in check_cython_extensions
        """ % src)
    Exception: Cython-generated file 'pandas/index.c' not found.
                    Cython is required to compile pandas from a development branch.
                    Please install Cython or download a release package of pandas.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-OD55P2/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-JQaDVa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OD55P2/pandas/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install pandas' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about your specific problem, but to answer your general question:

> Why would the same Dockerfile and docker build command successfully build on one machine, but raise an exception on another?

It's likely that the machines are using different `python:2.7` images.  Many images (especially official ones) are rebuilt often, and [the `python` tags page](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/) says `2.7` was last built 6 days ago.  If you just created the DigitalOcean instance, it would be using the latest `python:2.7`, but if you pulled that image more than six days ago, you would be using an out of date image.  If you run `docker pull python:2.7` on your local machine and try to rebuild, you should get the same error that you're seeing on DigitalOcean.

An alternative, yet related, possible cause could be [build caching](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache): If one of the many packages your Dockerfile installs has changed recently, but you haven't edited that line of the Dockerfile or any line above it recently, the Docker instance on your local machine would continue using the old version when building.  You can turn off the use of the build cache on your local machine by passing the `--no-cache` option to `docker build`.

Other possible reasons for a Docker build to succeed on one machine and fail on another include using different versions of Docker or using an HTTP proxy when downloading packages on one machine and a different proxy (or no proxy) on the other.

Comment: Very good explanation. I did build on my laptop several weeks ago and yesterday on Digital Ocean so that's probably the issue. I'll have to specify the image instead of using the latest.